# How to relocate face points in opencv / face distortion?

Tags: animation

I have to simulate facial expressions on a face image ( say open mouth ). For this I first extracted the facial feature points and found the corners of the lips. Now I need to deform the image by moving the points down.

[image]

In the above image I need to move the Pointe ( 2 ) and ( 3 ) to some distance left and right respectively. And point ( 18 ) and ( 19 ) littele bit down. So that I will get an expression like opened mouth.

**My Questions:**

1) Is this the above way right to proceed to simulate facial expression?
2) How to do this any language?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question doesn't have anything to do with design. Especially the coding aspect. In not even sure there's a place on SE for this, especially when you didn't show any code you've attempted on your own.